# Set_index() on a Pandas DataFrame giving unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas

I asked this question before but the question was downgraded for being unclear. So I deleted it.

I hope that this re-worked version will be much clearer!

The buggy code is part of a much larger project so it's not so easy to create a minimum example, especially as I am still fairly new to Python can almost completely new to Pandas, but if required I will try.

All_holdings is part of the portfolio object. Looking at it in the variables window it appears to be a list of dictionaries (is this correct)?

[image]

As you can see from the code it is then converted into a pandas data frame called curve using.

```
curve = pd.DataFrame(self.all_holdings)
```

At this point the curve data frame includes the columns 'datetime' and 'total' both containing the correct values from the original list of dicts in self.all_holdings.

[image]

However after performing:

```
curve.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

[image]

The 'datetime' column has disappeared and the column 'total' now has the 'datetime' values.
The original values of column 'total' have also disappeared?

I would have expected the 'datetime' column to become the index (but not for it's values to disappear) and everything else to stay the same?

Is this an issue of Python versions I am using 3.6 to his 2.7, also I'm using pandas 0.22.0 where as the example uses an unspecified earlier version.

Comment: The total values are still there, with an index of datetime, e.g. `1990-01-01 10000.0`

Comment: do *not* use screenshots. use text within the question to build a reproducible example that people can copy and paste into a text file for jupyter notebook

Comment: "...but if required I will try" -- you are always required to try. By creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you will better understand your own problem, and may perhaps even solve it without needing to as on SO. It should be thought of as a prerequisite to asking.

Comment: Also, do not call code that you do not understand "buggy". If you simply google "pandas set_index", you will quickly find very succinct [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), with visual examples, that explains exactly how what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue there. You did set an index on `datetime`. The `total` values are indexed on `datetime` too